# Looking for certain letters in a word

Tags: r

I have to write a function which puts out certain letters from a word and counts them.

E.g. `function("Testabc",letter[2:5]) = 3`, as only "b","c","e" are in the 2nd to 5th letters of the Roman alphabet.

Comment: So can we see your attempts? What did you try?

Comment: You informed us that you have a homework assignment, but failed to ask a question. What are you expecting us to *do* with the information that you have a homework problem?

Comment: what is the expected output as well as it format?

Comment: You might want to learn how to use `strsplit()`, `%in%`, and subsetting `[`, `[[`...

Comment: The description of the function is ambiguous. Should the output for `f("Testabce",letter[2:5])` be 3 or 4? In other words, is the counting according to multiplicity? Also -- does case matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the very limited information you provided

```
seek_count <- function(s,v) {
  as.data.frame(table(na.omit(factor(r<-unlist(strsplit(s,split = "")),levels = intersect(v,r))),dnn = "letter"))
}
```

Run `seek_count("Testabc",letters[2:5])`, you will get output like:

```
structure(list(letter = structure(1:3, .Label = c("b", "c", "e"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```